# QODBC wrong value for numeric

Tags: c++, sql-server, database, qt, odbc

I try to select numeric(20,0) values from a Microsoft SQLServer database. 
Therefore I connect to an Microsoft SQL Server over ODBC. I use the SQLServer Native Client 10.0 driver.

The way I connect and select data in my QT-project is the following:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", "DBConnection");
db.open();

query.exec("SELECT * FROM TABLE")
while (query.next()) {
   //Do something with query.value(0)
}
```

The problem now is when I look what kind of `QVariant` is returned from `query.value()` I see that it is a double. But double values are only good for about 16 digits and not for 20. For example in the select the value should be 10903012224000000001 but I get 10903012224000000000.

Is there any way to tell QT which type of value it should return?
An exact string value would suffice.

The way `query.value(0).toXXX` doesn´t work because it seems to start the transformation with the double value.

On topic:
i´m sure that the problem is in `QT`. When I use the same ODBC-Driver in a Java aplication I get the right values back.

Comment: Why don't you just change your database schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I found a bugreport https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-10451

The solution is to set numericalPrecisionPolicy from LowPrecisionDouble to HighPrecision
the following codeline is to add and then the qVariant is qString and everything works fine

```
db.setNumericalPrecisionPolicy(QSql::HighPrecision);
```